# Как создать постоянные переменные окружения в Linux

Tags: linux

Как создать постоянные переменные окружения в Debian, Ubuntu что бы их было видно во всех процессах , во всех оболочках и после перезагрузки их так же было видно везде?

Comment: См. `/etc/profile*` по крайней мере во многих дистрибутивах основные переменные там

Comment: Задача не имеет решения.

Comment: добавлял в ~/.bashrc , но почему то в другой терминальной сессия всеровно не видит мои перменные

Comment: Если другая сессия была открыта до добавления, то новых добавленных переменных в ней не будет.

Answer (score 3):

[вопрос в виду глобальности не имеет **ЕДИНОГО УНИВЕРСАЛЬНОГО** решения](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Environment_variables_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)#%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85).

«ближе» всего, пожалуй, файл `/etc/environment` для глобальных переменных и `~/.pam_environment` для переменных пользователя.

это **не** shell-скрипты, в них можно только объявлять переменные:

```
переменная=значение
```

Comment: Для **всех** процессов (даже в рамках одного и того же пользователя) это не работает. У задачи в принципе в широком понимании нет решения.